# Are Powershell Profile scripts dot-sourced?

Tags: powershell

The **Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1** script I am using creates a lot of variables when it runs. I have set all the variables' scope to "Script", but the variables used in the script never go out-of-scope.

I would like the variables to go out-of-scope once the script is done running and control is handed over to me.

If I compare the number of global, local, and script variables I have, I come up with the same number.

Example:

```
# Profile script does what it does.

Get-Variable -Scope Global | Measure-Object
Get-Variable -Scope Local  | Measure-Object
Get-Variable -Scope Script | Measure-Object

Output:
60
60
60
```

Currently, I am capturing a snapshot of the variables at the beginning of my profile script, then removing any new variables at the end.

Example:

```
$snapshotBefore = Get-Variable
$profileVar1 = 'some value'
$profileVar2 = 'some other value'
$snapshotAfter = Get-Variable

# Compare before and after, and create list of new variables.

Remove-Variable $variablesToRemove
```

Comment: I'm not sure of your goal. Why set the variables' scopes to `script`?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: The intent is to use temporary variables inside the profile that shouldn't linger once the profile has finished loading.

Comment: Ah. Yes, PowerShell profiles are dot-sourced.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, **PowerShell profiles are dot-sourced *by design***, because that's what **allows the definitions contained in them (aliases, functions, ...) to be *globally* available *by default*** - which is, after all, the main purpose of profile files.

Unfortunately, **there is no scope modifier that allows you to create a temporary scope for variables you only want to exist while the profile is *loading*** - even scope `local` is effectively global in a profile script; similarly, using scope `private` is also not an option, because the profile's script scope - due to being dot-sourced - *is* the global scope.

Generally speaking, you can use `&` (the call operator) with a script block to create variables inside that block that are scoped to that block, but that is usually at odds with creating *globally available* definitions in a profile, at least by default.
Similarly, calling another script without dot-sourcing it, as in your own answer, will not make its definitions globally available by default.
You *can*, however, **create global elements from *non*-dot-sourced script blocks / script by specifying the global scope *explicitly***; e.g.: `& { $global:foo = 'Going global' }`, or `& { function global:bar { 'global func' } }`.

That said, **the rationale behind dot-sourcing profiles is likely that it's easier to make all definitions global *by default***, making the definition of *typical* elements of a profile - aliases, functions, drive mappings, loading of modules - simpler (no need to specify an explicit scope).
By contrast, global *variables* are less typical, and to define the typical elements listed above you don't usually need script-level (and thus global) variables in your profile.

---

If you still need to create (conceptually) temporary variables in your profile (which is *not* a requirement for creating globally available aliases, functions, ...):

A **simple workaround** is to **use an exotic variable name prefix** such as `__` inside the profile script to reduce the risk of their getting referenced by accident (e.g, `$__profileVar1 = ...`).
In other words: the variables still *exist* globally, but their exotic names will typically not cause problems.

However, **your approach**, even though it requires a little extra work, sounds like a **robust workaround**, here's what it looks like in full (using PSv3+ syntax):

```
# Save a snapshot of current variables.
# * If there are variables that you DO want to exist globally, 
# define them ABOVE this command.
# * Also, load MODULE and dot-source OTHER SCRIPTS ABOVE this command,
#   because they may create variables that *should* be available globally.
$varsBefore = (Get-Variable).Name

# ... define and use temporary variables

# Remove all variables that were created since the 
# snapshot was taken, including $varsBefore.
Remove-Variable (Compare-Object $varsBefore (Get-Variable).Name).InputObject
```

Note that I'm relying on `Compare-Object`'s default behavior of only reporting *differences* between objects and, assuming you haven't tried to *remove* any variables, only the variables *added* are reported.

---

Note that while it can be *inferred* from the actual behavior of profile files that they are indeed dot-sourced - given that dot-sourcing is the only way to add elements to the current scope (the global scope, in the case of profiles) - 
this fact is not explicitly *documented* as such.

Here are snippets from various help topics (as of PSv5) that provide clues (emphasis mine):

From `Get-Help about_Profiles`:

> A Windows PowerShell profile is a script that runs when Windows PowerShell 
>   starts. **You can use the profile as a logon script to customize the 
>   environment. You can add commands, aliases, functions, variables, snap-ins, 
>   modules, and Windows PowerShell drives.** You can also add other 
>   session-specific elements to your profile so they are available in every
>   session without having to import or re-create them.

From `Get-Help about_Variables`:

> By default, variables are available only in the scope in which
>   they are created.
>
> For example, a variable that you create in a function is 
>   available only within the function. A variable that you
>   create in a script is available only within the script (**unless
>   you dot-source the script, which adds it to the current scope**).

From `Get-Help about_Operators`:

> . Dot sourcing operator
>      **Runs a script in the current scope so that any functions,
>      aliases, and variables that the script creates are added to the current
>      scope.**

From `Get-Help about_Scopes`

> But, **you can add a script or function to the current scope by using dot 
>   source notation. Then, when a script runs in the current scope, any 
>   functions, aliases, and variables that the script creates are available
>   in the current scope**.
>
> To add a function to the current scope, type a dot (.) and a space before
>   the path and name of the function in the function call.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and for amending your answer to better answer the question. You have done a good job. Let me point out one issue I found with my previous workaround (using snapshots and Compare-Object). When I loaded a module, and it created a Global variable. This variable would later be removed by this operation. This is why I was seeking a "better way" to do this, and was hoping proper scoping would solve it. Thank you again!

Comment: also I was curious if you had a source for your first paragraph **"PowerShell profiles are dot-sourced by design, because that's what allows the definitions contained in them (aliases, functions, ...) to be globally available "**.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer re loading modules - I've updated the answer with a caveat. You can still use the technique, you just need to place the variable snapshot-taking command carefully, after loading modules and dot-sourcing other scripts. I'm also curious about what are you actually doing in your profile, if it works for you to simply invoke another script with `&`, which the cannot create _global_ elements.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I do not doubt that the profile is dot-sourced. but I struggle to understand the "Why", and am inclined to see this as a bug and not a feature. Thank you for all the work you have done to providing a good answer. I have liked the "snapshot" approach for a while now, but it is a kludgy way of doing this task, so I set out to find a "better way", while hopefully sharing it here.

Comment: @B_Dubb86: My pleasure; as always, I learned in the process of answering. Let me try to explain the "why" again: the very purpose of profile scripts is to add elements (aliases, functions, modules, ...) to the _global_ scope, and the _most convenient_ way to add elements to an existing scope (the global one in this case) via a script is by _dot-sourcing_ that script. So it is very much a feature that profile scripts are dot-sourced - definitely not a bug. Perhaps I can clarify further if you tell me what you think profiles are for and what you actually do in yours.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply - I wondered why my global scope was cluttered with temporary variables from the profile script. I've just learnt about classes. Could one create a class in one's profile and stick everything in there but specify $Global when you need to set a global variable? Plus one can implement a sort of namespace?

Comment: @RobNicholson: You can think of `& { ... }` as a temporary, anonymous namespace: variables you create inside of the block go out of scope when processing of the block ends. This strikes me as simpler than declaring a class and instantiating it. Modules too have their own namespace - you get to control what gets added to the global namespace.

Comment: That's also a good idea and yes, easier than classes. To be honest, I hadn't come across classes until very recently so learning more about them was useful

Answer (score 0):

So it does sounds like Powershell dot-sources the profile. I couldn't find a resource that specifically says that, or other forums that have asked this question.

I have found an answer, and wanted to post it here.

I have changed my profile to only call a script file. The script now has its own scope, and as long as the variables aren't made global, they will go out-of-scope once the profile finishes loading.

So now my profile has one-line:

```
& (Split-Path $Path $profile -Parent | Join-Path "Microsoft.PowerShell_profile_v2.ps1")
```

**Microsoft.PowerShell_profile_v2.ps1** can now contain proper scope:

```
$Global:myGlobalVar = "A variable that will be available during the current session"
$Script:myVar = "A variable that will disappear after script finishes."
$myVar2 = "Another variable that will disappear after script finishes."
```

What this allows, is for the profile script to import modules that contain global variables. These variables will continue to exist during the current session.

I would still be curious why Microsoft decided to call the profile in this way. If anyone knows, and would like to share. I would love to see the answer here.

Comment: mklement0 already provided the answer to your question. The profiles are dot-sourced so the definitions are available globally.

Comment: I'm beginning to see where you're coming from: you're focusing on global _variables_, which however, are _not_ the typical
element to place in a profile; defining aliases, functions,and drive mappings, as well as loading of modules/snap-ins is much more typical.
Thus, it is more convenient to have those elements be global _by default_ - via dot-sourcing - than to specify a scope ever time.
Conversely, the question is: why do you have a need to define script-level variables in your profile?
In order to create the typical elements stated above, you do _not_ need script-level variables.